# Inconsistent results creating bidirectional relationship between PFUser and PFObjects

Tags: parse-platform

I am attempting to create a bidirectional relationship between a PFUser and some PFObjects using PFRelations.

First I create a Posting and save that in the background.
And in the completion block I add the new posting in the PFUser by appending to the list of Postings that are already related to this User and re-save the User with a synchronous save call.

The Posting is always saved correctly with the correct Relation to the User, however, the Relation back to the Posting in the User only works intermittently.  Stepping through the code results in the correct outcome each time which leads me to believe it's some sort of race condition.  What would cause this behavior?  Is there a better way to achieve the desired relationships?

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
PFObject *posting = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Postings"];
__weak HLReviewPostItemViewController *myself = self;

posting[@"title"] = self.createdItem[@"title"];
posting[@"price"] = self.createdItem[@"price"];

posting[@"owner"] = currentUser;

[posting saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        PFGeoPoint *currentGeoPoint = [myself.locationManager getCurrentGeoPoint];
        [currentUser setObject:currentGeoPoint forKey:@"geoPoint"];

        PFRelation *postingsForUser = [currentUser relationForKey:@"postings"];
        [postingsForUser addObject:posting];

        NSError *error;
        [currentUser save:&error];
        if (!error) {
            [myself.dataManager fetchLocalUsers];
        } else {
                NSLog(@"Error saving Posting in user relation: %@", error);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error saving Posting: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: This could be implemented as cloud code with an [afterSave](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave) action. When your Posting gets saved, get the current user, and add the relationship from them to the Posting.

Comment: Sure - but given that this seems like a valid approach I'm using I'm wondering why it is not entirely successful.  I'd also like to have less moving parts - avoiding cloud-code for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

When you save the `posting`, because the `posting` has a column that stores the `owner`, the owner - the parent, also gets saved automatically - very nice feature of Parse.

When you step through the code automatic save is executed and finished before your next re-save. But when you run the code, there is no guarantee which save to `PFUser` object would occur first.